# jsonp not working in js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
var api = "http://199.175.xx.xxx:3000?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON( api, {}).done(function( data ) {
        alert('h');
    });
```

but alert is never happening. I can see from network tab in inspector that request is being sent successfully and also response is the correct one but why alert is not firing inside done callback?

here is the inspector result
[image]

Comment: Does the URL correctly use the `jsoncallback` parameter to add the callback name to the response?

Comment: P.S. The `data` parameter in `$.getJSON` is optional.  You don't need to pass `{}`, you can just do ` $.getJSON(api)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat How to check its adding parameter correctly or not

Comment: Check the network tab for the response data?  What does it look like?  JSONP should look like this: `callback({"your": "data"})`.  Also, is it your API or is it a third-party one?  Are you sure it should be `jsoncallback=?`?

Comment: Its making request url like Request URL:http://199.175.xx.xxx:3000/?jsoncallback=jQuery111007484426628798246_1393260428362&_=1393260428363

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  What does the response look like, though?

Comment: Response is [{"datetime": "2014-02-23T10:02:34.417Z", "speed": 100}]

Comment: There's your problem right there.  It's not using the `jsoncallback` parameter in the response, like it's supposed to.  Did you create this URL, or is it a third-party API?

Comment: Like I said, it's not using the `jsoncallback` parameter in the response.  That needs to be fixed!  JSONP needs to be a function call, like `jQuery12345([{"datetime": "2014-02-23T10:02:34.417Z", "speed": 100}])`.  It's *not* JSON, it's different.  Did you create this API or is it a third-party one?

Comment: How can I move it? Do I need to fix it on server?

Comment: So, `199.175.xx.xxx` is your URL?  Yes, this is something that needs to be fixed in the *server-side* code.

Comment: Then you need to fix the server-side code to use the `jsoncallback` parameter.  Remember, JSONP is *not* JSON.  It's just a JavaScript file that usually contains a function call, containing (JSON) data.  Your response needs to be (example in PHP): `echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($data).')';`.

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way :

```
var api = "http://199.175.xx.xxx:3000?jsoncallback=?";
$.getJSON(api, function (data) {
    alert('h');
});
```

You don't need to use `.done()`here, as `$.getJSON` already comes with a callback function.

Source : [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: He doesn't *need* `.done()`, but it should work just fine with it.